# Regex replace in SQL Server Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have added a new column to a table and want to prepopulate it.

At the moment I have this:

```
update Table_A
set packages = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"name"; s:' + ltrim(str(len(p.name))) + ':"' + p.name + '";'+
                's:11:"category_id"; a:1:{i:0;s:1:"0";}}}'
from broker_product as Table_A
join scheme s on Table_A.scheme_id = s.id
join product p on p.id = s.product_ids
where Table_A.packages is null
```

What I want to do is populate `category_id` with a value based on the values of a column in `product`, as opposed to the fixed string that it is now.

An example of what is in `product.risks` is:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s:10:"field_name";s:24:"Gadget Accidental Damage";s:19:"risk_category_value";s:4:"1.00";s:13:"variable_name";s:24:"gadget-accidental-damage";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:10:"hover_text";s:0:"";}i:1;a:5:{s:10:"field_name";s:32:"Home Emergency Accidental Damage";s:19:"risk_category_value";s:4:"2.00";s:13:"variable_name";s:0:"";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:10:"hover_text";s:0:"";}}
```

In this example I would like `category_id` to be:

```
 a:2:{i:0;s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"1";}
```

which is an array of the same length as `products.risk`, with the values `i:0;s:1:"0";` for the size of the array, counting the number of elements in `product.risks`.

As an example, I am looking for something like this (with correct regex, not the broken stuff I've supplied):

```
update Table_A
set packages = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"name"; s:' + ltrim(str(len(p.name))) + ':"' + p.name + '";'
                's:11:"category_id"; ' + preg_replace('/a:(\d+):{(i:\d+;)/', 'a:$1:{$2s:1:"0";}', p.risks) + '}}'
from broker_product as Table_A
join scheme s on Table_A.scheme_id = s.id
join product p on p.id = s.product_ids
where Table_A.packages is null
```

Comment: You must know that SQL SERVER has really poor embedded support for regex. It does not use the standard regex notation (not in full extent anyway). You can search something like the following for information https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9112/precise-numerical-filtering-with-regular-expressions-for-tsql/

Comment: Look into CLR functions, you write your code in C# and import it into SQL and call your custon C# code to do your code.  I have done this for RegExpressions, sometimes specifric regex, or I wrote one to pass my own regex to the function to run on a string